# Sencha store not being populated

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am using variables to populate a Sencha data store with data from variables:

Here is my model:

```
Ext.define('axis3.model.Gauges', {
    extend: 'Ext.data.Model',
    config: {
        fields: ['Title','CurrentValue','BaseValue','CentreValue','Generated'],
    }
});
```

Here is my store:

```
var store2 = Ext.create('Ext.data.Store', {
   model: 'axis3.model.Gauges',
   data: [Title,CurrentValue, BaseValue,CentreValue,Generated]
});
```

I know that the variables are being populated, as I am using them in other places in the same function (console log)

When I use `console.log(store2)` it shows [object object]
When I use `console.log(store2.data.variableName)` it shows undefined.

How do I correct this?

Comment: check `store2.data.items` on console

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@MMT, thanks

```
store2.data.items[0].raw
```